# How can I get my Realtek RTL8111/8168B NIC working?

Tags: networking, drivers

I've come to a dead end with another Linux distro due to the difficulty of obtaining or compiling device drivers for a Realtek RTL8111/8168B NIC that is onboard a new server mobo I was planning to use in a render farm project.  I can live with downloading and installing pre-compiled proprietary drivers (e.g. Nvidia) but was hoping to avoid having to compile them and learn how to install them then hope they were not broken in a future kernel upgrade which seems to happen.  Though an experienced developer, I have scant experience with Linux and no time to plough through the learning curve.  Is there any joy for me by way of out-of-the box support for an r8168 NIC?  There are no spare PCI slots and it's either find a ready solution or give up on Linux (which I really am loath to do).  Grateful for any constructive comment.

Answer (score 1):

For *Ubuntu Server 20.04*, you can do this with a little help of the `universe` repository. Here's how:

0. Open your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use a different editor if you're not keen on* `vi`. *This is more muscle memory than an implicit recommendation.*
1. Find this line:

   ```
   deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
   ```

   ***Note:** You're probably not pulling from the Japanese mirror, so do not use* `jp` *unless you're on the same side of the globe.*
   Add `universe`, so the line becomes:

   ```
   deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe
   ```
2. Save the file
3. Update `apt` for the new repository:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Pull down the `r8168-dkms` package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
   ```

   ***Note:** This may take some time, as* `dkms` *will compile the driver after pulling it down. Once the driver is compiled, the network adapter should start up immediately. If it doesn't, then you may need to restart the system.*

That's all there really is to it. For the server I was using, I had a USB⇢Ethernet adapter that allowed me to connect the machine to the network so that I could download the drivers (and other updates). Once everything was good, the USB adapter was thrown back into the "Bag of Useful Adapters" that I keep handy.

Hope this helps you should you replace Fedora with Ubuntu

Comment: Great Matigo.  Very much obliged.